# SHH Tunnel From Node JS to ASW RDS MySQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am working on a project with a partner. The project's backend is node js, and our db is an AWS RDS MySQL DB. Our overall issue is properly communicating with the DB over SSH within NodeJS. Below is what we have configured so far, based on research I have done for the past few days. The code will show the configuration for our SSH Tunnel, our DB, and the result after we make our API call. Any help or advice will be highly appreciated!

Our SSH Tunnel Config

```
const { createTunnel } = require ('tunnel-ssh');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

async function createSSHTunnel(srcAddr = process.env.SSH_HOST, srcPort = process.env.SSH_PORT) {
    const tunnelOptions = {
        autoClose: true,
    };

    const serverOptions = {
        port: srcPort,
    };

    const sshOptions = {
        host: process.env.SSH_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.SSH_PORT),
        username: process.env.SSH_User,
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'JD KeyPair.pem')),
    };

    const forwardOptions = {
        srcAddr: srcAddr,
        srcPort: srcPort,
        dstAddr: process.env.DB_Host,
        dstPort: parseInt(process.env.DB_Port),
    };

    try {
        await createTunnel(
            tunnelOptions,
            serverOptions,
            sshOptions,
            forwardOptions
        );
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
            // Assume port is uniquely used by SSH tunnel, so existing connection can be reused
            console.log(`Returning existing SSH tunnel on ${srcAddr}:${srcPort}.`);
            return { srcAddr, srcPort };
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(`SSH tunnel successfully created on ${srcAddr}:${srcPort}.`);
    
    return { srcAddr, srcPort };
}

module.exports = { createSSHTunnel };
```

Our DB config

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql2/promise');
const { createSSHTunnel } = require ('./sshTunnel');
require('dotenv').config();

const { srcAddr, srcPort } = createSSHTunnel();

const db = createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_Host,
    port: process.env.DB_Port,
    user: process.env.DB_User,
    password: process.env.DB_Pass,
    database: process.env.DB_Data,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0,
});

module.exports = db;
```

One of our API calls

```
router.post('/retrieveCardInfo', async (req, res) => {
  const cardID = req.body.CardID.CardID;

  try {
    const uploadCardStatus = await db.query('SELECT * FROM cardstorage WHERE cardID = ?', [cardID]);

    if (typeof uploadCardStatus[0][0] !== 'undefined') {
      return res.send(uploadCardStatus[0][0]);
    }
    return res.json({errorMessage: "Card Not Found"});
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.json({ errorMessage: 'A Server Error Occured!' });
  }
});
```

The result of our API execution

```
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: undefined,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
```

Comment: Does this work when you try it on your local machine using local ssh keys and a local instance of mysql?

Comment: Check your Security Group for port 22 or whatever you have set. Timeout issues are often related to improper SG

Comment: Hi, what port did you use? I am trying to access port 22 but not working.

Comment: Hi am trying to do the same. But facing timeout error. Can you please specify what ports you are Using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resolution was to allow all traffic for rds securities under EC2 security groups. Once done, I configured my connection to our RDS MySQL BD using 'createPool' like so...

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql2/promise');
require('dotenv').config();


const db = createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_Host,
    port: process.env.DB_Port,
    user: process.env.DB_User,
    password: process.env.DB_Pass,
    database: process.env.DB_Data,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0,
});

module.exports = db;
```